# How to fix error: code 500 in javascript in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

If anyone knows how, please help me fix this error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve module ../Components/View/ReactNativeViewViewConfig from C:\YandexDisk\бизнес\Python\acer_17_inch\tests_react_native\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image\ImageViewViewConfig.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\View\ReactNativeViewViewConfig(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\View\ReactNativeViewViewConfig\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 | 
> 13 | import ReactNativeViewViewConfig from '../Components/View/ReactNativeViewViewConfig';
     |                                        ^
  14 | import type {ReactNativeBaseComponentViewConfig} from '../Renderer/shims/ReactNativeTypes';
  15 | 
  16 | const ImageViewViewConfig = {
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlItW.jpg)

Comment: What is the path of the file where your `import` statement is?

Comment: It's not my import that causes the error. The module "node_modules" causes an error

Comment: add the code, the one that's throwing the error. It's hard to solve an issue just by looking at the error log. But from the looks of it the import statement is throwing in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error by updating with the 'expo update'command

Answer (score -1):

Error is telling you what is wrong,Read carefully

```
Unable to resolve module ../Components/View/ReactNativeViewViewConfig from C:\YandexDisk\бизнес\Python\acer_17_inch\tests_react_native\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Image\ImageViewViewConfig.js:
```

Check your import path

Comment: It's not my import that causes the error. The module "node_modules" causes an error